# Adding item at the top of a list in Parse (local datastore enabled)

Tags: android, sorting, parse-platform, local, datastore

I have followed the tutorial "http://www.michaelevans.org/blog/2013/08/14/tutorial-building-an-android-to-do-list-app-using-parse/.

What I can't seem to figure out is to place a new item at the top of the list and not at the bottom like in the tutorial.

I've been trying to solve it with sorting, but since it did not work I am now solving this issue by loading the list items from Parse - which gives me the correct order of the objects. This results in to many unnecessary requests to Parse.

I have enabled Local Datastore and I read somewhere that the above issue is due to Local Datastore.

Very grateful for help with this!!
br
Susanna